# Can we use Truncate function inside a function?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can we use Truncate function inside a function ?
I want to know if I execute TRUNCATE TABLE query in a function would it truncate the table ?

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do? Perhaps a table variable is a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TRUNCATE` isn't a function, it's a DML operation. Functions in SQL Server (just like in C# and many other languages) are followed by parentheses; for example `GETDATE()`, `ISNULL({NULLable Expression},{Return Expression if prior NULL})`, `dbo.DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD({Delimited List},{Delimiter character})`, etc.

And no, you cannot use `TRUNCATE` inside a function. A Function cannot perform any DML operations apart from against table value variables that are declared within the function itself (and then you are using a multi-line function, which tend to perform poorly).

If you need to be performing DML operations, you want a Stored Procedure.

Comment: So I've been studying about Truncate lately and I think TRUNCATE is DDL operation as it's auto-commited. I'm not sure still trying to clear out things but that's what I learned so far. If TRUNCATE would have been DML it could've been roll backed.

Comment: A `TRUNCATE` can be rolled back, @DoonieDarkoo. but then, so can a DDL statement. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7e703859975433f025fd31444181f6bf)